Adjust button padding dynamically
I have this button, which is using the bi-list icon, which increases by 5px when hovered over. I like this, but the only issue I have come across while trying to do this is that it also increases the size of the button, which in return screws up the responsiveness of my navbar entirely. How can I set the button to have dynamically change the padding within, to accommodate for the size change of the icon?
Not Hovered Over:

Hovered Over:



("use strict");

// Navbar Dropdown
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle(600);
});
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css");
header {
  background: black;
}


/*navbar begin*/

.navbar {
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  --bs-navbar-brand-padding-y: 0px;
  --bs-navbar-brand-margin-end: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand-text {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, magenta, magenta, lime);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 300% 100%;
  background-position: left center;
  transition: background 0.18s linear;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  .navbar-brand-text {
    background-position: 100% center;
  }
}

.navbar-brand:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-brand>.navbar-brand-text {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 370px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #808080;
  transition: color linear 0.18s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.nav-link:focus {
  color: #ff00ff;
}


/*navbar end*/


/*dropdown begin*/

.dropdown-menu {
  background: #111;
  --bs-dropdown-min-width: 100px;
  --bs-dropdown-border-radius: 10px;
  --bs-dropdown-border-width: 2px;
  --bs-dropdown-border-color: #ff0000;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #808080;
  transition: color linear 0.18s;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: #ff00ff;
  background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown-menu a:focus {
  color: #ff00ff;
  background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown-divider {
  border-top: 1px solid #252424;
}

.dropdown-item:active {
  background: #111 !important;
}

.dropdown-item:focus {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #ff00ff !important;
}


/*dropdown end*/

/* start icons */
.navbar-toggler .bi-list {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #969696;
    transition: font-size 0.18s linear, color 0.18s linear;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover {
    .bi-list {
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #ff0000;
    }
}

/* end icons */
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Cratex Studios</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" />
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid justify-content-between">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#leftMainNav" aria-controls="leftMainNav" aria-label="Toggle left navigation">
                        <i class="bi-list"></i>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
          <img style="width: 30px" src="assets/images/logo-l.png" />
          <span class="navbar-brand-text">Example Brand</span>
        </a>
        <div class="d-flex" style="width: 240px">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Company</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu position-absolute" style="top: 55px; width: 110px">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/mission.php">Mission</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/partners.php">Partners</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/affiliates.php">Affiliates</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/legal.php">Legal Info</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/support.php">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/team.php">Our Team</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-menu mt-1 ms-2 me-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#signupModal">
                            Sign Up
                        </button>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="rightMainNav" aria-labelledby="rightMainNav">
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white justify-content-end" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="rightMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body justify-content-end">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-end">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="leftMainNav" aria-labelledby="leftMainNav">
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="leftMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>



It is the left toggler button I'm currently working on right now.
I have tried using scale() and using the calc() function.

"I have tried using scale()" - that has no effect on inline elements. Give .bi-list display: inline-block.

Thanks to Cbroe, I have figured out what was preventing it from working. The scale() function does not work on inline elements. Be sure to add display: inline-block to any icons you want to dynamically adjust the size to.
